# control the size of data for kendo grid excel functionality

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, grid, export

i have a kendo grid that loads data dynamically. when there is small set of data the Excel export works fine.  when there is a large set of data, the excel export craps out because the data is too long for JSON.

my q is, how do i detect that my read func in the controller is being called by exporting to excel functionality and limit the size of data in the controller?

thanks,
Inna

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://www.kendoui.io/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport). It gives an example for the `excelExport` event that fires when you click the Excel export button.

Comment: i am using the excelExport already to format the data being exported.  but it does not work for the situation described above, because at this point the JSON error has already occurred.  the event is getting the JSON string as input.  the question is how to detect that the controller function that generates the JSON string is being called by the Read of the Kendo Grid is called from the Excel Export button.   thanks.